# HPC usage statistics

Tags: history, hpc, usage-statistics

In HPC, we can get the real time usage statistics using qstat, pbsnodes, showq. But is there a way to get the usage history or is the usage history saved in some log files? I am interested in getting the usage history of particular user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Torque keeps logs in the server_priv/accounting directory of the Torque install. Maui keeps logs in the stats directory of the Maui install. You should be able to grep the files corresponding to the dates you are interested in. In the past, I've opened up Maui stats in a spreadsheet as a space delimited file with some success.